# Infix, prefix or postfix order trough BST to get descending order of printed elements

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I know that if we print the BST in the infix order i will get ascending order of elements the tree contains. How to get descending order? Using postfix or prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither postfix nor prefix will give you descending order. You need infix again, but descend down the right child first (when normal traversal descends down the left first).

Answer (score 0):

```
p = root;
push(p);
p = p->rightchild;
while(stack is not empty) {    
    while(p != NULL) {
        push(p);
        p = p->rightchild;
    }
    p = pop();
    print p->data;     
    if(p->leftchild != NULL) {
        p = p->leftchild;
    }
}
```

Comment: please add some explanation too!!